# Python JSON append if value doesn't exist

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I've got a json file with 30-ish, blocks of "dicts" where every block has and ID, like this:

```
{
      "ID": "23926695",
      "webpage_url": "https://.com",
      "logo_url": null,
      "headline": "aewafs",
      "application_deadline": "2020-03-31T23:59:59",
}
```

Since my script pulls information in the same way from an API more than once, I would like to append new "blocks" to the json file only if the ID doesn't already exist in the JSON file.

I've got something like this so far:

```
import os

check_empty = os.stat('pbdb.json').st_size
if check_empty == 0:
    with open('pbdb.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write('[\n]')    # Writes '[' then linebreaks with '\n' and writes ']'
output = json.load(open("pbdb.json"))

for i in jobs:
    output.append({
        'ID': job_id, 
        'Title': jobtitle, 
        'Employer' : company, 
        'Employment type' : emptype, 
        'Fulltime' : tid, 
        'Deadline' : deadline, 
        'Link' : webpage
    })

with open('pbdb.json', 'w') as job_data_file:
    json.dump(output, job_data_file)
```

but I would like to only do the "output.append" part if the ID doesn't exist in the Json file.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. It's JSON Lines and you'll have to scan the file each time to look to see whether the ID exists; that's gonna be O(N), so gets progressively slower as the dataset grows. Or you can try keep something in memory to keep track of seen IDs? Is there a reason that you're not using a database?

Comment: Actually, it's not even JSON Lines because you're putting the carriage return in a list. I don't know what you're trying to do

Comment: it writes the data in output.append to a json file and it looks pretty much like this image: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/images/create-schema-array.png
I don't know if that's valid or not but it's not throwing any errors atm, it's just a fun project for me to learn, and since the dataset would never be that big, I thought a JSON or CSV file would work well enough, I'm pretty new to this, would a database make this much easier?

Comment: That is valid JSON, but you haven't shown the newlines. Yes, a database would make this easier

Comment: any recommendations for a good, lightweight database that works great with python?

Comment: Sqlite3 is bundled with python. It has its limitations but it'll do almost everything a full-blown RBDM will

Comment: In light of the whole JSON format issue, can you edit your post to reflect what the question actually is?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to complete the code you provided but I added an example to show how you can achieve the none duplicate list of jobs(hopefully it helps):

```
# suppose `data` is you input data with duplicate ids included
data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'mary'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'george'}]

# using dictionary comprehension you can eliminate the duplicates and finally get the results by calling the `values` method on dict.
noduplicate = list({itm['id']:itm for itm in data}.values())

with open('pbdb.json', 'w') as job_data_file:
    json.dump(noduplicate, job_data_file)
```

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense because it just overwrites duplicate data

Comment: You are right, however having an id means data are duplicates and from the question, it seems that having one copy of each is sufficient and overwriting should not matter.

Comment: That's not true. You have no guarantee on the order of records, generally, with JSON. So you have no idea which value of a duplicate key would be saved

Comment: Here is the quote from the question `Since my script pulls information in the same way from an API more than once, I would like to append new "blocks" to the json file only if the ID doesn't already exist in the JSON file.` which means duplicate data are coming in.

Comment: Great. And your answer doesn't deal with that. The very act of opening the file in write mode just wipes its contents

Comment: I dont wanna be tormenting you; there's a few things that make this approximation fall down. Please consider them

Answer (score 0):

I'll just go with a database guys, thank you for your time, we can close this thread now